# Jquery bind click event to all form fields using delegate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my HTML

```
<div class="dc2-contact-cont" selectedindex="1" id="contact-form-applet">
<div class="dc2-ltfc">
    <div class="dc2-ltfcs">A
        <br>
    </div>
    <div role="row" class="dc2-ltfcc" id="0">
        <p><span class="dc2-ltf-span" id="SIO_Contact_First_Name_Label">First Name</span>
            <br>
            <input type="text" aria-labelledby="SIO_Contact_First_Name_Label" id="0_SIO_Contact_First_Name" name="s_5_2_30_0" class="dc2-ltf-input" value="555" aria-readonly="false">
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="dc2-ltfc">
    <div class="dc2-ltfcs">B
        <br>
    </div>
    <div role="row" class="dc2-ltfcc" id="1">
        <p><span class="dc2-ltf-span" id="SIO_Contact_First_Name_Label">First Name</span>
            <br>
            <input type="text" aria-labelledby="SIO_Contact_First_Name_Label" id="1_SIO_Contact_First_Name" name="s_5_2_30_0" class="dc2-ltf-input" value="4444">
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to bind click event to all the input controls inside div but I am not able to find the right selector.

I tried following expression but it didn't work

```
$('.dc2-ltfcc p').delegate("input[type=text], textarea",
    "click", {
        ctx: this
    },
    function(event){
        console.log("clicked");             
    });
```

Here is a link to jsFiddle where I tried to use find to get the right selector but I am not able to select even the div.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YC9rw/1/)**

Comment: I think {cts:this} within delegate is going wrong. Can anyone give the right answer for this?

Comment: ctx:this is right. it passes the context of the current function

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KNVrc/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using `on`:**

```
$("#contact-form-applet").on("click","input",function() {
alert('test');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YC9rw/2/)**

**Using `delegate`:**

```
$( "#contact-form-applet" ).delegate( "input", "click", function() {
alert('test');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YC9rw/3/)**

Comment: Why `on` ..OP asked for `.delegate()`

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
$('.dc2-ltfcc p').on('click','input',function() {
     console.log("clicked");
});
```

Note: [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is deprecated from version `1.7`, you should use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead like above.

Comment: @Pilot `deprecated` does not means as `removed`

Answer (score 0):

Use **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

The `.on()` syntax is the new syntax that version 1.7 uses and it is meant to substitute `.bind()`, `.delegate()` and `.live()`.

for more ->http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/

```
$("#contact-form-applet").on('click','input',function() {

// your desire action     
});
```